# Troubles with std::lock_guard<std::mutex> and if constexpr block

Tags: c++, templates, mutex, lock-guard

There is a class template `Foo<T>`. And for some specific type, a function should use `lock_guard`.
Here is the example code:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>

template<typename T> 
class Foo {
public:
    void do_something(int k) {

        if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, NeedMutexType>) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx_);
        }

        resource_.push_back(k);
        // code for task with resource_ ...
    }

private:
    std::mutex mtx_;
    std::vector<int> resource_;
};
```

The `std::lock_guard` will destructed in the end of if constexpr scope. (If it's not true, please correct me.)

To handle this, I can copy the code for task with `resource_` below into the if constexpr scope, or just use the raw `std::mutex` such as `mtx_.lock()` & `mtx_.unlock()` instead.

Is there any some ways to handle this with `std::lock_guard` ? Thanks.

Comment: What about using [std::conditional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) to select either `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>` or some kind of null type __e.g._ `struct fake_lock { fake_lock(std::mutex&){} };`

Comment: Why not to create helper `unique_ptr<lock_guard<mutex>>` which is assigned in if constexpr block and released at the end of do_something scope ?

Comment: @rafix07 Good start, but then a `unique_lock` instead of a `unique_ptr<lock_guard<...>>` may be even cleaner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps [std::conditional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) could come to the rescue here, if you need to do this kind of thing a lot.

```
template<class Mutex>
struct FakeLockGuard { FakeLockGuard(Mutex&){} };

template<typename T, class Mutex = std::mutex>
using OptionalLock = typename std::conditional<
    std::is_same_v<T, NeedMutexType>,
    std::lock_guard<Mutex>,
    FakeLockGuard<Mutex>>::type;
```

Here we've defined a do-nothing class template that's constructed the same way as `std::lock_guard`. We then use that with `std::conditional` to select either `std::lock_guard` or `FakeLockGuard` depending on the result of your type-check.

Now you can use it as follows:

```
template<typename T> 
class Foo {
public:
    void do_something(int k)
    {
        OptionalLock<T> lock(mtx_);
        resource_.push_back(k);
        // ...
    }

private:
    std::mutex mtx_;
    std::vector<int> resource_;
};
```

You can easily verify this works by setting a breakpoint in the `FakeLockGuard` constructor or making it output something.

That's how you can make it all work at compile-time. But I think as you alluded to already, you can simply construct a `unique_lock` and then conditionally lock it. This has the benefit of being much clearer to whoever has to work with your code. In the end, it's up to whatever you think is most appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

Just construct the lock in the unlocked state then lock it later:

```
template<typename T> 
class Foo {
public:
    void do_something(int k) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_, std::defer_lock);
        if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, NeedMutexType>) {
            lock.lock();
        }

        resource_.push_back(k);
        // code for task with resource_ ...
    }

private:
    std::mutex mtx_;
    std::vector<int> resource_;
}
```

Note that you'll need to use `std::unique_lock` for this as `std::lock_guard` can't be constructed unlocked

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two different functions:

```cpp
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx_);
resource_.push_back(k);
// code for task with resource_ ...
```

```cpp
resource_.push_back(k);
// code for task with resource_ ...
```

So you can package the common stuff into a different function:

```cpp
private:
    void do_something_unlocked(int k) {
        resource_.push_back(k);
        // code for task with resource_ ...
    }
public:
    void do_something(int k) {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, NeedMutexType>) {
            std::lock_guard lock(mtx_);
            do_something_unlocked(k);
        } else {
            do_something_unlocked(k);
        }
    }
```

---

The general fix to `if constexpr` creating its own scope is to put it in a lambda:

```cpp
void do_something(int k) {
    auto maybe_lock = [&]{
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, NeedMutexType>) {
            return std::lock_guard{mtx_};
        } else {
            return 0;  // Dummy value; no lock needed
        }
    }();
    resource_.push_back(k);
    // code for task with resource_ ...
}
```

Which is just barely less typing than the helper function, but could be easier to use (especially if you use it multiple times and make a member function `auto maybe_lock()`)